# End SaveStateComplete - Why can be so time consuming?

Tags: asp.net, performance

What this part is doing? Especially why its time consuming, if I dont have ViewState and big object graph? It can take sometimes 3rd of request speed.

Found that this problem, is only on dev server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also noticed that this stage is comparatively expensive even without ViewState (even with a nearly blank page)

I was able to speed this stage up drastically by running my project on my local IIS instance rather than running on the Visual Studio development web server. Compiling in release mode versus debug mode seemed to give a marginal improvement as well.

My guess is that 1) it is nothing to worry about and 2) the VS web server may be less optimized than IIS for some piece of the process. For example, IIS may cache machine values (such as registry settings, certificates, etc) and the VS web server may not.

If during SaveStateComplete an encryption routine is run (such as when `EnableViewStateMac="true"`), a call to local machine resources might be much more expensive running on the VS web server even if nothing is actually being encrypted.

I don't consider this a great answer; if you are really concerned you could profile ASP.NET to see what it is actually doing (for example, which BCL methods are being invoked).

Answer (score 0):

the role of SaveStateComplete is to save control viewstate/controlstate before it is rendered. So, unless you have disable viewsate(EnableViewState="false" at page level) for your page/controls, the job is always done. Moreover, disabling viewstate doesn't disable controlstate.
Do you have many controls on your page?

Comment: No. I can say even 0 controls.